# Prove that a solution to differential equation is unbounded

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system:

$$ \begin{cases}
x'=x-6y\\
y'=-2x-y
\end{cases} $$

I want to prove that the solution to the system which satisfies $$ x\left(0\right)=1,\thinspace\thinspace y\left(0\right)=0 $$

is unbounded, **Without solving the equation.**

My work so far:

Notice that this system is hamiltonian system, meaning: $$ \begin{cases}
x'=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}H\left(x,y\right)\\
y'=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H\left(x,y\right)
\end{cases} $$

Where $ H\left(x,y\right)=x^{2}+xy-3y^{2} $ and the solution $\varphi$ which satisfies $\varphi(0)=(1,0)$ also satisfies $$ \varphi\left(0\right)\in\Lambda_{1}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\thinspace:\thinspace H\left(x,y\right)=1\right\} =\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\thinspace:\thinspace x^{2}+xy-3y^{2}=1\right\}  $$

And the level curve $\Lambda_1$ is hyperbola (which means it is unbounded).

Now, I tried to assume by contradiction that $\varphi(t) $ indeed is a bounded solution, which means that both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are bounded, but I cannot find how to reach a contradiction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Assume that $x,y$ are bounded. Let $X(t)=e^{-t}x(t)$ and $Y(t)=e^{-t}y(t)$. Prove that $X^2-3Y^2$ is increasing in $t$ and then get a contradiction.

Comment: @Feng I proved that $X^2-3Y^2$ is increasing in $t$, wihch means that also $x^2-3y^2$ increasing in $t$ and hence has a finite limit, which means that also $xy$ has a finite limit. How do I get the contradiction?

Comment: $X^2-3Y^2$ takes $1$ at $t=0$. If $x$ and $y$ are bounded, then $X$ and $Y$ must tend to $0$ as $t\to\infty$. But we have proved that $X^2-3Y^2$ is increasing. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now let me write a detailed answer using the idea in my early comments, at which time I was typing on my not-so-smart phone.

We argue by contradiction. Suppose that $x(t), y(t)$ are bounded on their maximal interval of existence, then they must exist on the whole interval $[0,\infty)$, by the standard continuation theorem (*e.g.* [Theorem $4$ in this pdf](http://www.math.pitt.edu/%7Esph/1275/1275notes4-13.pdf).) Define
$$X(t)=e^{-t}x(t), Y(t)=e^{-t}y(t),\qquad t\in[0,\infty).$$
Then $X, Y$ satisfy the equations
$$ \begin{cases}
X'=-6Y,\\
Y'=-2X-2Y,
\end{cases} $$
with $X(0)=1, Y(0)=0$. It follows from the boundedness of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}X(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}Y(t)=0.\tag{$*$}$$
Let $f(t)= (X(t))^2-3(Y(t))^2$, then $f'(t)= 12(Y(t))^2\ge 0$ for all $t>0$, thus $f$ is non-decreasing on $[0,\infty)$. Since $f(0)=1$ by the initial data, we must have
$$f(t)\geq 1,\qquad t\in[0,\infty).$$
But $(*)$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$. This is a contradiction!

Comment: Can I ask how did you knew to define $X,Y$ and $f$? what was the intution behind?

Comment: @FreeZe Indeed, I tried something else and other ideas failed, only the idea in my answer worked. My first try is to multiply $x'=x-6y$ by $x$ and multiply $y'=-2x-y$ by $y$, then try to cancel the term $xy$, so $(x^2-3y^2)'=2(x^2+3y^2\geq 0$ thus $x^2-3y^2$ is increasing. But this doesn't help. After that, I realized $x'=x-6y$ can be written as $x'-x=-6y$ and the $x'-x$ has a special structure: $(e^{-t}x)'=e^{-t}(x'-x)$. So I defined $X=e^{-t}x$ and $Y=e^{-t}y$, then performed the same strategy to cancel the term $XY$, and it worked! There may be some other ways to do the proof, too.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see
$$ \frac12(x^2-3y^2)'=x(x-6y)-y(-2x-3y)=x^2+3y^2\ge x^2-3y^2 $$
which implies
$$ (e^{-2t}(x^2-3y^2))'\ge0. $$
So
$$ x^2-3y^2\ge (x^2(0)+y^2(0))e^{2t}=e^{2t}. $$
This gives
$$ x^2+y^2\ge x^2-3y^2\ge e^{2t}. $$
So $(x,y)$ is unbounded.

Comment: A little suggestion: Strictly speaking, your last inequality doesn’t imply the boundedness unless the maximal interval of existence is $[0,\infty)$. So, you may need to split this into two cases. If the maximal existence time is $T<\infty$, then the solution blows up by the standard continuation/extension theorem. This case is easy, but at least we should mention that. Or, you can also prove that the solution exists on the whole $[0,\infty)$, without solving the equation.

Comment: Since the system is linear, the maximal existence time is $T=∞$.